# vector is sum of atmost $2$ eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix (nothing is given about base space, we can assume it to be $\mathbb{C}$) such that $A^2=I$. Then any $n\times 1$ vector is sum of atmost two eigenvectors of $A$..

Let $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $v$ is not an eigenvector i.e.,
$Av\neq v$ and $Av\neq -v$

I have no idea how to proceed..

Please give only hints.

Comment: The definition of $v$ not being an eigenvector is not what you wrote down but rather that there is no $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ with $Av = \lambda v$

Comment: @Fryie : It is not the definition.. As eigenvalues are $\pm 1$ i have written that

Comment: @cello Their product is $(0, -1) = -1 \cdot (0,1)$.


Reposting deleted hint: If the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm 1$, then every nonzero $n \times 1$ vector is the sum of how many eigenvectors? What about the zero vector?

Comment: Hmm...looks like I have no idea what I'm talking about.

Comment: Since you have the eigenvalues, consider the eigenspace for each eigenvalue. What is their dimension? Consider their direct sum. What does that say about any vector in the space?

Comment: @Peter : This seems to be another good approach... If a matrix is given then i can see its eigenspace but for random matrix i do not know :O I want to know

Comment: The important thing is that the dimension of any eigenspace is at most the multiplicity of the eigenvalue. So when you direct sum your eigenspaces, you get at most $n$. The "at most" is because you have to consider also the dimension of the null space. But what is the dimension of the null space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Given a vector $v$, consider the vectors $v+Av$ and $v-Av$.

Comment: $A(v+Av)=Av+A^2v=Av+v$ and $A(v-Av)=Av-A^2 v=Av-v=-(v-Av)$ and $2v=(v+Av)+(v-Av)$. To get $v$ may be we should consider $\frac{v}{2}+A(\frac{v}{2})$ and $\frac{v}{2}-A(\frac{v}{2})$.. Thanks. How did you come up with some thing like this?

Comment: I realized that A would take these vectors to a multiple of themselves (and that they would be nonzero if v is not an eigenvector).

Comment: Ah... I have written that $v\neq Av$ and $v\neq-Av$.. I should have considered these non zero vectors $v-Av$ and $v+Av$...